# PHP. Узнать настоящее расширенее файла

Tags: php

Обрабатываю файлы в php скрипте после получения их с формы.
Предполагаю, что пользователь может послать мне измененный файл (к примеру, заменить у файла shell.php расширении на image.jpg). В этом случае на моем сервере потенциально может храниться дыра, которая приведет к нарушению безопасности.
Хочу обрабатывать такие случаи и не давать пользователям присылать то, что мне не нужно.
Сейчас мой скрипт проверяет тип файла просто по его окончанию. Как лучше организовать проверку реального типа файла?
В одном фреймворке видел такую проверку в одну строку кода, но не хочу брать что-то тяжелое для простых задач.

Comment: Я думаю, что вам надо смотреть содержимое файла и если оно отличается от ожидаемого, то можно и сообщить пользователю, что не поддерживаем такой тип данных...

Comment: Полноценная проверка вряд ли возможна (существуют явления вроде rarjpeg, [программы внутри корректной bmp-картинки](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588649) и т.п.) Если вы совсем сильно боитесь чего-нибудь, лучше не допускать ничего от пользователя и конвертировать всё подряд (от конвертирования jpg→jpg немного потеряется качество, но зато результат точно будет безопасным)

Comment: А вообще если ваш сервер позволяет выполнять php-код из картинок, то вам надо не проверки добавлять, а ваш сервер перенастраивать. Даже если shell.php переименован в image.jpg (а впрочем даже если не переименован) — на корректно настроенном сервере это не должно быть проблемой даже при отсутствии проверок.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это всё фантазии. Нет никакого "настоящего расширения файла".

Проблема тут в том, что люди почему-то считают, что файл может быть какого-то одного типа. Но если подумать, то это очень смешное заблуждение. Один и тот же файл может содержать элементы, которые разными программами будут интерпретироваться совершенно по-разному. поэтому идея найти какой-то "настоящий" тип файла заранее обречена на провал.

Расширение у файла есть только одно. И твой веб-сервер будет судить о том, как этот файл интерпретировать, именно по расширению. И файл shell.jpg будет совершенно безобиден, если твой веб-сервер не настроен на исполнение файлов jpg как РНР, и если твой код не инклюдит файлы по выбору пользователя.

Что можно сделать - это *примерно* определить, по первым нескольким байтам содержимого файла, к какому типу он скорее всего относится. Это можно сделать функциями `mime_content_type()` или `finfo_file()`.

**Никакой гарантии в плане безопасности это не даст**, но может отсечь совсем тупые попытки взлома или битые файлы.

Основной же защитой является именно проверка по расширению.

Плюс для картинок может помочь пересоздание, но это не точно. Есть опыты которые показывают что вредоносный код может пережить и такое. Тем более что для других типов файлов, например pdf, такое не подойдет.

Если нужна проверка изображения на корректность, то можно попробовать конвертировать его. Если попытка удалась - значит файл как минимум интерпретируется как изображение.

Если совсем уж заботит безопасность, то пользовательские файлы можно класть на отдельный сервер - свой или CDN